# count records and select from table those < field value

Tags: mysql

First thanks for the time.

I am asking for any advise here.

I have two tables inv and asig as follows

```
inv has invID, name, ans, mx
asig has stuID, invID
```

I have a query working but I need to expand it.

The actual query is

```
SELECT
inv.invID,
inv.name
FROM invest
WHERE (inv.invID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT asig.invID from asig))
```

I get the records from inv that aren't in asig as expected

Now what I need is to get all the records from inv that inv.mx < the count of times invID appears in asig.

I figured this query:

```
SELECT 
invID, 
COUNT( invID) as number 
FROM asig 
WHERE 1
group by invID
```

and gets me the actual times invID is in the asig table, so I tried to apply this query in the previous one (without any luck)

```
SELECT
inv.invID,
inv.name
FROM inv
WHERE (inv.mx < (SELECT invID, COUNT(invID) as number FROM asig WHERE 1 group by invID))
```

Of course I got an error (Operand should contain 1 column(s))

I cannot compare one number with two numbers but I am lost here. I don't know how can I do this comparison.

Any hints are appreciated

Editing>>>

My asig table has 1328 records and I should get 954 in the query. I do this in excel to verify the results.

invID is an uniuqe index and always populated. mx is always >= 0

Answer (score 0):

This query should get all the inv records and their mx values that don't have a record in the asig table, and also all records in the inv table where the mx values are less than the number of records also in the asig table.

```
SELECT inv.invID, inv.mx
    FROM inv LEFT OUTER JOIN asig
    ON inv.invID = asig.invID 
    WHERE asig.invID is NULL
UNION  
SELECT inv.invID, inv.mx 
    FROM inv INNER JOIN asig 
    ON inv.invID = asig.invID 
    WHERE asig.invID IS NULL 
    GROUP BY inv.invID
    HAVING COUNT(asig.invID) < inv.mx
```

Comment: Thanks you Misandrist. I tried you solution and I got this error: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns. The only thing I see is the first select has 2 columns and the second has 3.

Comment: I just edited it to only have the COUNT in the HAVING clause. Let's see if that works. If not I'll set up the schema here too and give it a try.

Comment: I tried and as is, took 20 seconds and result in 19k records, :). After I chenged the first IS NULL to IS NOT NULL I got the 954 records. Now I have to review if those are the ones I need

Answer (score 0):

For each invID, its number of appearances in asig is

```
 select count(*) from asig where indID=@invID
```

Now you compare them

```
 select * from inv where mv < (select count(*) from asig where asig.invID = inv.invID)
```

Comment: a correlated subquery that can be avoided is a correlated subquery best left unused.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know how to put 2 statements in one query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to join to your query as a derived table - not use it as a correlated subquery.

```
select inv.*
  from inv
    inner join (
      SELECT invID, COUNT( invID) as number 
        FROM asig 
        group by invID
    ) q
    on inv.invid = q.invid
      and inv.mx < q.number
```

[fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/588f6/1)

Comment: NOTE: This query will return *extra* rows from the inv table because of the outer join (e.g. when an `invID` value from `inv` doesn't appear in `asig`).  To fix that, the last line of the query "**`and inv.mx < q.number`**" would need to be replaced with something like "**`WHERE inv.mx < IFNULL(q.number,0)`**".  (The `IFNULL` could be replaced with the equivalent and more ANSI-compliant `COALESECE`, or that `IFNULL` expression could be ditched in favor of an `OR`...

Comment: @spencer7593 actually that was deliberate. but my head was thinking greater than for some reason. and inner join would probably make more sense.

Comment: The `INNER JOIN` will omit rows where `mx` is negative, and `invID` doesn;t appear in `asig`. (If `mx` is unsigned, or we have some other sort of gurantee that it will never be negative, then it's not a problem.)  Personally, I'd just negotiate to have the specification changed, "returns rows from inv where mx>=0 and mx < the number of times invID appears in asig", so it doesn't get bounced back from QA as a "bug".

Comment: @spencer7593 well it's hard to determine from the question what these values represent, so at this point it's all just speculation - OP can decide from here i think.

Comment: Pala, I tried this and gets also the 23 records as well. Thanks

Comment: @notuo Can you please provide sample data because i don't see how that's possible

Comment: @notuo here's a quick demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/588f6/1  the results seem correct as per your requirements

Comment: @notuo are you able to provide any more information here?

Answer (score 0):

There are several query patterns that will return the specified result.

Assuming that `invID` is UNIQUE in `inv` table, you could use straightforward `JOIN` operation, and a `GROUP BY`, count the number of times `invID` appears in `asig`, and compare that to the `mx` column in a `HAVING` clause

For example:

```
  SELECT inv.invID
       , inv.name
    FROM inv
    JOIN asig 
      ON asig.invID = inv.invID
   GROUP
      BY inv.invID
       , inv.name
  HAVING inv.mx < COUNT(asig.invID)
```

NOTE: This query depends on a *guarantee* that `invID` is UNIQUE in the `inv` table, and omits any rows where `invID` is `NULL`.

This is an example of just one possible query pattern.

**EDIT**

This query does not return a "zero count" for values of `invID` that don't appear in the `asig`, which is a concern if `mx` can be negative.

To fix that, we can add another condition to the `HAVING` clause

```
  HAVING inv.mx < COUNT(asig.invID)
      OR inv.mx < 0
```

And make the join an "outer" join by specifying `LEFT JOIN` in place of `JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you Spencer. 

First. invID is the primary key and mx is >= 0 always as you assumed correctly.

I just tried your sample and got a very small number of records. (23)

My asig table has 1328 records and for example I got 1 record (invID in asig appears only once and in the inv table, mx is 5) This invID never shows in the query you offer.

My inv table has 4473 records

I am reviewing my question as well. I may wrote that wrongly.